How do I use a proxy with chromium-shell-headless?
I am using AWS ECS and docker.
I have chromium-shell version 129.0.6668.100-1~deb12u1 from https://snapshot.debian.org/package/chromium/
And I am using node:20.18.0-slim
I'm starting a proxy server, and this works from chromium new headless and chrome.
However it seems chromium-shell cannot connect to it. I'm getting the error
ERROR:bus.cc(407)] Failed to connect to the bus: Could not parse server address: Unknown address type (examples of valid types are "tcp" and on UNIX "unix")
I'm using puppeteer pointed to chromium-shell and an arg
"--proxy-server=protocol://localvariation:port"
where I've been trying combinations that do not seem to work for instance
protocol http, tcp, unix
localvariation 127.0.0.1 localhost 255.255.255.0
port is the port the proxy is started on. For new headless I can do
"--proxy-server=localhost:port" and it seems to work...
Edit: I've resolved the tcp errors by setting up networking tools and running
dbus-daemon --system --fork --print-address 1 > /tmp/dbus-system-addr.txt; \     
export DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS=$(cat /tmp/dbus-system-addr.txt); \     dbus-daemon --session --fork --print-address 1 > /tmp/dbus-session-addr.txt; \     
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(cat /tmp/dbus-session-addr.txt); \     echo 'DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS=' $DBUS_SYSTEM_BUS_ADDRESS; \     
echo 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=' $DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS; 

However, the traffic still needs to be routed through the proxy and is not.
Does anyone know why chromium-shell would bypass the proxy rather than connect to it?
Edit 2:
I no longer believe the issue is with chromium-shell itself.
I think the issue is related to the binary.
Using a binary from https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp-proxy (I copied the built binary out of the docker container)
The copied chromium-shell connects to the proxy.
